# Get date from url and change selected date on jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

after searching for a bit I decided to ask this question.

I have a jquery datepicker that is in a form, and after changing the date and clicking submit the url will look like this: `index.php?thedate=12%2F22%2F2012#` which is really **12/22/2012**. I then need it to extract the url and change the selected date to whatever is in the url. So for my early example of **12/22/2012**, the selected date on the calendar would be the 22nd.

Here's my code:

```
<form method='get' action='#'>

    <div id="datepicker"></div>
    <input type='hidden' id='thedate' name='thedate' />

    <input type='submit' value='SUBMIT' id='submit'/>

</form>
```

and my javascript:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
        alert(dateText);
        document.getElementById('thedate').value=dateText;
    }
});
```

Thanks for any and all help! If you need any more details or specifics, please just ask!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the date format. Do this:

`$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", 'mm/dd/yy' );`

You also can specify 2 date formats. One for presentation purposes `dateformat` and another one the real date to use in you application. This last one is the `altformat` and must be togehter with the `altfield`, this field is a field that stores the picked date in its alternate format.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
  dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
  altFormat: "mmddyy",
  altField: "#alt-date"
});

<input type="hidden" id="alt-date"/>
```

Therefore you can use this `altField` (usually a `hiddenField`) to store date and send it to the server.

**[TEST IT](http://jsfiddle.net/GKfZM/566/)**